# Drupal - Stop Custom Variables In Content

Tags: php, templates, drupal, drupal-7

I have had a look in the preprocess_page hook and i can't work out how to do this. I have added a custom field called "thumbnail_url" to the blog post type. But when the blog post is displayed Drupal is automatically putting the image tag to the bottom of the post.

I actually want to move the image above the post content, but i can't work out how i would do it. So it's basically taking the custom variable and adding it to the end of the content.

Answer (score 0):

In your content type, go to "manage display" and reorder fields.